# LED as 230V AC indicator

Tags: led, mains

Answers to other questions here (e.g. [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42647/mains-power-indicator-maximum-current-draw)) show capacitors used to drop AC voltages to levels suitable for a LED. I've seen much simpler circuits such as the one below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVIPNN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming it's in a suitable enclosure, are there significant drawbacks or dangers to this circuit compared to others?

Comment: If your goal is just to indicate that mains voltage is present, a neon lamp may be a better solution, not requiring a high-power resistor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The types of AC powered LED drivers I've seen use a capacitor to drop the voltage/limit the current and to that extent it uses less "real" power.

The circuit you've drawn will (for normal 1.8V LEDs) pretty much dissipate 1W so it will get a little warm.

I guess the inability to pack some punch is the main drawback. The current into the LED is about 8mA every positive cycle so you don't get much light out compared to the heat.

I don't think there are any dangers (other than those you excluded)

Comment: How does one drop voltage with a capacitor more efficiently than with a resistor? Are you talking about some sort of non-linear conversion?

Comment: The power companies won't charge you for imaginary power @PhilFrost

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, Christmas tree LED lights are essentially this, with many LEDs in series to increase the diode's combined forward voltage to something closer to the AC voltage, reducing the voltage across R1, and thus the power. They also seem to include half the diodes in anti-parallel, so for each AC half-cycle, half the LEDs are lit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKU6oK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The obvious disadvantage of this circuit is the power lost in R1. This means a very low efficiency.

The LED is also on only half the time, and when it is on, has high ripple current. [LEDs get less efficient as the instantaneous current increases](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/does-pulsing-an-led-at-higher-current-yield-greater-apparent-brightness), so this further reduces efficiency. And, it blinks at 50Hz, which to me, is very noticeable and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit defined here gives a 8mA current and the resistor wattage should be atleast 2W for safe operation. P=I2.R (0.008x0.008x27000=1.72W)

Comment: And how much power is dissipated when the diodes are not conducting?

Comment: @AndrewMorton -- assuming diode leakage is insignificant, none, although it's not the greatest design as the LED is only on for the positive half cycles...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I know that. You know that. I was hoping Ramesh would think about it w.r.t. the power dissipation of the resistor.