# Indicator LED directly to AC mains. Which method would you use?

Tags: led, ac, mains

Some EE would do it like [this](https://electronicsarea.com/light-emitting-diode-connected-to-120-240-vac/), or another variant [here](http://www.turbokeu.com/myprojects/acled.htm) using a capacitor and a resistor in serie with the led and a diode in parallel with the led (see links).

But what's the advantage (or disadvantage) over simply joining a resistor and a diode in serie with the led (see schematic below)?
(R1 value calculated for 380 VAC. LED 20mA, 2V)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwRh7L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After reading the first comment, I designed this variant: Would the diode in serie with the LED (instead of being in reverse parallel) save energy during the unused half cycle?

The Cap has an impedance of 15K. Does the calculation of power loss and heat apply in the same way as with a 15K resistor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f55rJe.png)</sup>

Comment: Calculate the power dissipation of the resistor

Comment: Plus the LED will flicker hideously.

Comment: Does it mean that the combined resistance of the cap and the resistor (1K in the example form the link) is much less than the resistance in the simple desing? And that with the cap, it will not flicker or flicker less?

Comment: The cap won't reduce flickering, but it will reduce heating, because the capacitor manages to reduce the current without creating much heat.

Comment: Thanks. I reedited my question. And now the question is: Does the impedance of the cap has less effect on heating and power loss than that of an equivalent resistor? (15K according to the article) or does the fact of charging and discharging limits this effect?

Comment: Same question was asked here. But didn't extend the question on the cap impedance. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76985/led-as-230v-ac-indicator?rq=1

Comment: Your second circuit simply does not work. The capacitor will charge up to the peak voltage and the LED will be out.

Comment: You may find this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q23uh7AjjXw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Cap has an impedance of 15K. Does the calculation of power loss and heat apply in the same way as with a 15K resistor?

No, the impedance of the capacitor is purely [reactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power#Reactive_power). It dissipates no real power.

EDIT: as drawn the circuit does not work. You want this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8gFoh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The value of C1 must be chosen to limit the current to the correct value. 470nF gives a current of 21mA, which flows alternately through D1 and D2.

R2 serves to 'bleed off' the high voltage on C1 when the device is disconnected, to prevent the user from being shocked. R1 limits the current to C1, preventing a spark when the device is plugged in, and also protects C1 against brief voltage surges.

Comment: Thanks. There is a lot to read about it as I can see on your link. Simple answers are very useful.

Comment: Not so, the capacitor will simply be charged up to the peak voltage. The circuit does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I understand, the reverse parallel diode is necessary to allow curent to flow in both directions to alow the cap to charge and discharge alternatively?

Comment: This website shows the 1M resistor connected between the two phases instead of bypassing the cap. What do you think? http://www.turbokeu.com/myprojects/acled.htm

Comment: The two leds solution would lower the flickering effect visualy (if soldered close enough to each other) https://electronicsarea.com/light-emitting-diode-connected-to-120-240-vac/

Comment: .... the change made that does fix the problem is that it now conducts on both halves of the AC waveform. Obviously you could use two LEDs back to back as well or one LED and a small bridge rectifier to take advantage of the current flow in both half cycles to get greater indicator brightness.

Comment: @JackCreasey while current is flowing, very little power is wasted during the negative half-cycle - D1 only wastes 15mW or so.

Comment: @Fredled putting the 1meg across the phases instead of the cap is the same effect, it just means the bleed off current goes through the diode as well.

Comment: Just a note guys. Due to inrush current during an AC peak cycle we had to make R1 600 ohms, as 3 200 ohm ww resistors, just in case the power source was 600 VAC.

Comment: @Sparky256 was that to protect the capacitor or the diode? Do you mean 1 cycle of 600VAC surge, or continuous?

Comment: @Tek. To protect our 1N4007 diodes (as a 3-phase bridge), rated for only 1 amp. If the power main was 600 VAC as in our Canadian products, then it was continuous. We also used reactive power supplies for the diagnostics. Much cheaper than transformers.

Comment: Both websites I linked to made a mistake in their reactance~impedance/capacitance calculation: They wrote 47uF where it should be 470nF: 100x smaller! (thanks  τεκ for including the right number in his schematic). I wonder if other websites make the same mistake (some mistake are universal it seems)

Comment: Also shouldn't the formula I=V/R become I=V/2*R since only half of the cycle is used?

Comment: @Fredled The current flows through D1 for one half cycle and D2 for the other. The *RMS* current through C1 is 21mA. The *average* current through D1 is 9.5mA.

Comment: So the "average" current through D1 is RMS of V/2? That's how you got 9.5 and not 10.5mA?