# What is the most efficient way to detect if AC mains is live for interfacing with a microcontroller?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, ac, mains, reactance

I want to implement an electrical mains level detector to interface with a microcontroller the simplest and most efficient way possible as this circuit would always be on. I’m trying to detect when a thermally protected MOV has blown. I only need to know the binary state. I don’t want to use ADC, just a general purpose IO pin. I don’t like using an optocoupler/isolator as these would all need to draw a few milliamps. I’d like to get this down to the tens of microamps, as that’s probably all that’s needed for setting a level on CMOS pins. I’ve modified this circuit [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357821/indicator-led-directly-to-ac-mains-which-method-would-you-use) and came up with this. I used an online calculator to help figure out a good range on C1/C2. Note, the connection between the DC ground and AC ground is optional, but I needed to do that to test with my scope. I have not decided on the rest of the circuit if I want to join the AC/DC grounds.

[image: Mains detection circuit]

I have more than a few questions that hopefully can be answered.

1. If you remove the connection between ground and neutral, does this effectively provide isolation up to the working voltage on the capacitor?
2. Do the capacitors need to be X or Y rated safety caps? Ceramic or film?
3. In this case, I assume R1 and R2 need to be split to handle the working voltage of about 200V, correct?
4. Using a 5.1V zener produces only 4V at the output regardless of the value of R3 (0.47k-100k). Where did the other 1.1V go? Something to do with D1? I’d like to know how to calculate for a 3.3V output
5. Increasing R1 and R2 had a fairly noticeable impact on current draw. How to choose a good value?
6. Are there any simplifications possible here?

Comment: What would the MCU do with this information? Does the MCU have any external connections, which  determines if it even requires to be isolated or if it can be non-isolated. Whatever you do, do not connect mains neutral and mains earth together, not even through your scope. The RCD will trip, and what if you plugged the mains plug in with the orientation that connects live to the mains earth through scope. Do you want this to be safe, cheap, low power and easy to build - they are contradicting requirements.

Comment: There is an option to use a small 60Hz transformer with low magnetising current.

Comment: Reckon 1500 V for R1 and R2 if you want to be safer through mains transients if you must use a direct connection. Michal's transformer, or an opto, are far better solutions. An opto doesn't need mA.

Comment: I would use an optoisolator the maximum value of the collector resistor is set by the controller input switching threshold and the opto leakage current. The leakage current is typically of the order of 500nA.

Comment: What you name "optional" wire ... this can't be used ... Ground of V1 can't be wired with the low pin of D2.

Comment: yep, optoisolator

Comment: @Justme, yes all of these! I realize it is a tradeoff.

Comment: @Michal Do you know of a reasonably priced transformer which will not eat up a bunch of board space and have micro-amp draw?

Comment: @Neil_UK Wouldn't I simply need a 3-400V cap in this case, especially given the MOV surge protector there? Most caps I've seen tied directly to AC lines at least here in the US, are rated around that, e.g. motor start/run caps. Can you recommend and efficient optoisolator? I have only seen 1-5mA ones.

Comment: @RoyC So I can use an optocoupler to achieve low current draw? How can I find the minimum current needed by the LED for a given datasheet?

Comment: @PeteW If using an opto, would it be advantageous to still use the R1/2  and C1/2 to drop the voltage down to reduce the power wasted as heat? Also, how to choose the resistors, caps for minimum (uA) current draw for the LED?

Comment: @Justme Yes, I realize you shouldn't connect AC earth and neutral. That is only done at the main panel at the service drop, at least here in the US. There will be a power outlet switched by the controller, and there will be buttons, so I'd like at the end to tie DC ground to low voltage AC reference, e.g. neutral. I didn't think about a miswiring. Maybe a big low voltage TVS from neutral to earth to trip the breaker if it is miswired?

Comment: @fivejeez No, you should not connect neutral to low voltage side. Unless the thing is unisolated and untouchable anyway and without external connections.

Comment: The LED will be driven from the AC. Is the current draw on the AC important?

Comment: @RoyC Yes, I would like this to be as low as possible, hopefully less than a few microamps as this will always be on. Also, need to keep the heat down. 1mA at 120V is 120mW. I've ordered an ac-input opto so I can start testing. I assume there is a balance between current draw and noise immunity. Is that right?